# How can convert mod_rewrite rules to nginx rules

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, nginx

Does not get converted. help

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css/common|robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml|test\.html|sitemap\.xml)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: http://winginx.com/en/htaccess + http://www.anilcetin.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to improve you question-asking skills. It would be nice to see that you tried something of even checked you original configuration wihtout calling for help with a copy-paste (duplicate entry...).

Automated tools can at best try to apply pre-cooked recipes or 1 -> 1 relations between Apache and nginx rules.

They will fail at understanding what you wish to do and will most probably won't give you the best/cleanest/leanest/most recommended solution.

Here, for example, @Cheery tool even ignored the condition... -_-'

Try the following:

```
location /index.php {
}

location /images {
}

location /css/common {
}

location /robots.txt {
}

location /sitemap.xml {
}

location /test.html {
}

location / {
    # Use 301 instead of 302 for permanent redirect
    return 302 $scheme://$host/index.php$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip Bernard. I sat on a couple of hours to read the FAQ, I realized that you can not do much differently then what I want. I sorry for my English, and for the fact that you took the time.